# Navegación por Json desde php

Tags: php, json

Tengo este Json

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "total_count": 1,
    "usr_api_reg": [
        {
            "name": "Ya existe una cuenta con ese nombre de usuario. Pruebe con otro nombre de usuario.",
            "token": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Y accedo al campo name de esta forma:

```
$obj = json_decode($json); 
$resultado=$obj->{'usr_api_reg'};
    foreach ($resultado as $data)  
            {  
            $rst=$data->name;
            }
```

En mi caso, no necesito el valor de token para nada. 
Como puedo acceder a name sin tener que hacer el foreach? He intentando algo asi pero nada.

```
nombre= $obj["usr_api_reg"]["name"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si imprimes el objeto resultante de hacer el `json_decode`verás que obtienes algo así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Ya existe una cuenta con ese nombre de usuario. Pruebe con otro nombre de usuario.
            [token] => 
        )

)
```

Si sabes cierto el índice al que quieres acceder, puedes hacerlo directamente.

Fíjate que tienes un objeto dentro de un array, por lo tanto debemos acceder al índice del `array` para lo que se utilizan el operador  `[n]`, una vez hemos accedido al índice deseado del `array`nos falta acceder al atributo del objeto, en ete caso 'name' para acceder se utiliza el operador `->`
en este caso para acceder directamente al campo que te interesa puedes hacer esto:

```
echo $resultado[0]->name;
```

que devuelve esto:

> Ya existe una cuenta con ese nombre de usuario. Pruebe con otro nombre
>   de usuario.

Si el `json`devuelve más de un registro y desconoces el íncide, no tienes más remedio que iterar para buscar el valor deseado.

Comment: Justo estaba poniendo lo mismo, te adelantaste! :)